# Websocket disconnect after certain time

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a little nodejs server with the "ws" the websocket server work fine but the client disconnect automatically and the readyState go 3.
Can i stop this ?

Comment: It depends upon why it is disconnecting.  One reason people use socket.io on top of webSocket is that it does automatic reconnection when the connection drops.  But, if it's disconnecting because the client device goes to sleep or loses network connection, then socket.io won't help.

Comment: Ok, so my websocket goes off because i leave the tab on chrome no ?
Can i fire an event if i re-open the tab ?

Comment: See page visibility API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: I'll read that ! Thanks